# Desktop icons become corrupted, applied Vista Shortcut Manager with no success

Tags: windows-7, windows

My desktop icons became damaged when I installed Quickbooks 2013. A generic file image is now overlaying the icon. I applied Vista Shortcut Manager to add the arrow; this worked, but I want to remove the arrow. Using Vista a second time to remove the arrow, the arrow is replaced with the generic file image.